# Order by in django doesn't work well

Tags: python, django

I have this model in my django project:

```
class Archivos(models.Model):

    ramo = models.ForeignKey(Ramo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    anyo = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    semestre = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    detalle_tipo = models.IntegerField()
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='archivo/', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.ramo, self.anyo, self.semestre, self.tipo, self.detalle_tipo, self.extension)
```

When I try to make a query of this objects, ordering by -anyo (Year descending), the list of objects are ordering ascending.

This is my query:

```
archivos = Archivos.objects.filter(ramo=ramo.id).order_by('-anyo', 'semestre','detalle_tipo')
```

I've try adding a Meta class in my model like this:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-anyo']
```

But the list is still ordering ascending. It doesn't matter if the query is ordering by anyo or -anyo.
How to solve this?

I'm using the latest version of Django.

Comment: The query looks correct. Are you iterating `archivos` or just printing it ?

Comment: Also, which database are you using ? It shouldn't affect it, but just to try to reproduce it.

Comment: Can you provide the output of this query?

Comment: Yes, I'm iterating `archivos`, and I'm using Postgresql.

Comment: My output (Looks fine):
`<QuerySet [<Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2017 1 Exámen 0 pdf>, <Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2017 1 Solemne 1 pdf>, <Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2017 1 Solemne 2 pdf>, <Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2017 1 Control 4 jpg>, <Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2017 2 Exámen 0 pdf>, <Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2017 2 Solemne 2 pdf>, <Archivos: CIENCIAS BÁSICAS Cálculo CBM Cálculo III 1006 2016 2 Exámen 0 pdf>]>`

Comment: To iterate archivos I'm doing this in my html 
`{% for Archivos in archivos %}
  {{ Archivos.anyo }}
{% endfor %}`
But the html render show anyo descending.

Comment: The queryset you have posted looks fine. Perhaps you have not saved your changes or restarted your server after changing code, so you are not running the code you think your are. Or there might be an error in your urls/view (which you haven't shown), so that `archivos` is not the queryset you think it is.